# Sorting by highest average in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a code to find the average for all files in a directory, saving them into a list, and then ordering by average number. For example, files list is ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']

and scores list is ['4.67', '5.33', '6.33', '5.33']

which makes student_average_list ['me: 4.67', 'you: 5.33', 'him: 6.33', 'her: 5.33'].

I want to sort it so that it becomes ['him: 6.33', 'you: 5.33', 'him: 5.33', 'me: 4.67'].

There is no syntax error, it just sorts it incorrectly. Thanks for all help

```
def sort_average():
    scores = []
    student_average_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        file = os.path.join(path, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            with open(file, 'r') as txt_file:
                data = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in txt_file]
                average = (sum(data) / len(data))
                average = ("{0:.2f}".format(average))
                scores.append(str(average))

    for x, y in zip(files, scores):
        student_result = (x + ": " + y)
        student_average_list.append(student_result)

    student_average_list.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[-1]), reverse=True)
    print(student_average_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace

```
for x, y in zip(files, scores):
    student_result = (x + ": " + y)
    student_average_list.append(student_result)

student_average_list.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[-1]), reverse=True)
print(student_average_list)
```

With

```
import operator
results = zip(files, map(float, scores))
results = sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
student_average_list = ["{}: {:.2f}".format(x, y) for x, y in results]
print(student_average_list)
```

That way you create a sorted list before converting into a string. It will make it much easier.
No need to convert the scores into a string in the middle. It's a waste.